# Intellij cannot access

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've tried to write this code in IntelliJ Idea, but it didn't allow me to compile.Error log: Cannot access Stack.Node.
But if I compile it using windows cmd, code will be compiled.
What's wrong with ItelliJ?

```
public class Stack {

    private Node first ;

    private class Node {
        private String item ;
        private Node next ;
    }

    public void push(String item) {
        Node second = first ;
        first.item = item ;
        first.next = second ;
    }
}
```

[IntelliJ screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Moy.png)

Comment: I have no idea at all why IntelliJ won't compile this.  And I don't have my own copy of IntelliJ to try it out on.  However, to make this code work, you'll need to add `first = new Node();` between lines 11 and 12.  Otherwise you'll get a null pointer exception the first time you call `push`.

Comment: Move mouse on error and read description

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, and it just compiles without error in my version of IntelliJ (Recent version of community edition + java 8). Which version are you using ? My guess is that it's just a temporary error.

And as David Wallace mentioned, you will get a NullPointerExeption on invoking push().